# R dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am now a new programmer to R. I am now using dplyr package. The package suggests we transfer data.frame to tbl_df().

What happened if I did not do such transformation? Will it cause a problem when using the functions (e.g., select, filter, mutate) in dplyr package? Thanks.

Comment: The only reason (in my view) to change from strictly `data.frame` to `tibble` (which is what `tbl_df` does) is for console interpretation: if you have a 1M row frame named `x` and accidentally type `x<Return>` on the console, R will happily show all 1 million rows ... which may take time and clobbers your interface. A `tibble` will show the top so-many rows (configurable) and tell you that there are 999,990 other rows not shown. Other than that, all of the `tidyverse` verb-functions will happily work on a `data.frame`.

Comment: As r2evans said above, tibble is good for visualizations. If you want to learn more I recommend reading http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/tibble-data-format-in-r-best-and-modern-way-to-work-with-your-data

Comment: @r2evans Thanks a lot. Because I forgot to add tbl_df() on one of my data.frame. Thus, I want to make sure it does not cause any trouble.

Comment: The `dplyr` functions will automatically change it whenever they need it to be a tibble.